# Django JQuery autocomplete showing No search results

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-autocomplete

I'll directly go to the code

**models.py**

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = CountryField(choices=list(countries))
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**template.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'registration/jquery.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="tags"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**jquery.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                        source: "{% url get_restaurant %}",
                        selectFirst: true,
                        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^get_restaurant/$', views.get_restaurant, name='get_restaurant')
```

**views.py**

```
def get_restaurant(request):
    term = request.GET.get('term')
    bslk = Restaurant.objects.filter(name__icontains=term)
    res = []
    for b in bslk:
        dict = {'id':b.id, 'label':b.name, 'value':b.name}
        res.append(dict)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(res),'application/json')
```

I used the following import:

`import simplejson` for views.py

I have values for name in Restaurant models, but the problem is autocomplete is showing `No search results!`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you have in your `bslk` variable? Is it empty? Try to print it in your view.

Comment: @inlanger ran it in shell and got the following query: SELECT `registration_restaurant`.`id`, `registration_restaurant`.`name`, `registration_restaurant`.`owner`, `registration_restaurant`.`city`, `registration_restaurant`.`state`, `registration_restaurant`.`country`, `registration_restaurant`.`contact` FROM `registration_restaurant` WHERE `registration_restaurant`.`name` LIKE %qw%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery.js` is a static file which is not preprocessed by django template engine.  So you have to replace the `{% url %}` tag with the hard coded url:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                        source: "/get_restaurant/",
                        selectFirst: true,
                        minLength: 2
   });
});
```

Or somehow pass this url from template to js.  For example:

```
<script>
    var restaurantAutocompleteUrl = "{% url 'get_restaurant' %}";
</script>
<script src="{% static 'registration/jquery.js' %}"></script>
```

And then in the JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                        source: restaurantAutocompleteUrl,
                        selectFirst: true,
                        minLength: 2
   });
});
```

Another option is to wrap the JS binding code into the function and call this function from the template:

```
<script src="{% static 'registration/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    bindAutocomplete("#tags", "{% url 'get_restaurant' %}");
</script>
```